# Intersection of collection of sets when given one is a subset of the other...

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove a proposition in Topology, however, in order to do so...it appears I need the following to be true. Hopefully, someone can validate this along with my proof. Thanks!

Is the following true:

Let $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ and $\{E_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in B}$ be two arbitrary collection of sets. If $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A} \subseteq \{E_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in B}$, then the following inclusion holds:
$$\bigcap_{\beta\in B} E_{\beta} \subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} I_{\alpha}.$$

Quite naturally, I can think of examples where this holds. For example, take the following two collection of sets:
$$I = \{\{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,c,d\}\} \implies \bigcap I = \{a,b\}.$$
$$E = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,c,d\}, \} \implies \bigcap E = \{a\}.$$
And so we have that $I \subseteq E$ and $\bigcap E \subseteq \bigcap I$.

(My attempted) Proof:

Let $x \in \bigcap_{\beta\in B} E_{\beta}$, then for every $\beta \in B$ we have $x \in E_{\beta}$. This is where I get stuck. I know (probably) that at this step I need to use the fact that
$\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A} \subseteq \{E_{\beta}\}_{\beta \in B}$, however, I am not sure how to properly word this... maybe something like...for each $\alpha \in A$, there exists a $\beta \in B : 
I_{\alpha} = E_{\beta}$. Therefore, for each $\alpha \in A$ we have that $x \in I_{\alpha}$. This implies that $x \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} I_{\alpha}$. Hence, the following inclusion holds:

$$\bigcap_{\beta\in B} E_{\beta} \subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} I_{\alpha}.$$

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indices actually make this harder than necessary. Suppose that $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are collections of sets such that $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$; then $\bigcap\mathscr{B}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{A}$.

To prove this, suppose that $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{B}$; then $x\in B$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$. And $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$, so clearly $x\in A$ for each $A\in\mathscr{A}$, and therefore $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{A}$. Thus, $\bigcap\mathscr{B}\subseteq\mathscr{A}$.

Note that this is intuitively obvious when you think about it right: to get $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$ you’re intersecting all of the sets in $\mathscr{A}$ **and possibly some more sets besides**, and those extra sets, if then do anything at all, can only shrink the intersection even further.

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, in your response did you mean $\bigcap \mathscr{B} \subseteq \bigcap \mathscr{A} $, instead of $\bigcap \mathscr{B} \subseteq \mathscr{A} $?

Comment: @DaltonPettway: I certainly did; thanks for catching that! Fixed now.

Comment: No problem, thanks as always!

Comment: @DaltonPettway: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Brian’s answer and intuition are great, and here is my pedagogically-inspired version of his index-free answer. I particularly wanted to give a proof that avoided “intuitively obvious” (or similar language, like “clearly.”)

Suppose that $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$. We need to show that $\bigcap\mathscr{B}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{A}$.

Let $b$ be a particular but arbitrary element of $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$. If we show that $b$ is in every element of $\mathscr{A}$, we can conclude that $b\in\bigcap\mathscr{A}$, and we are done.

Let $A\in\mathscr{A}$ be a particular but arbitrary element of $\mathscr{A}$. Because $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$, it follows that $A\in \mathscr{B}$. But $b$ is an element of $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$, so $b$ is an element of every set in $\mathscr{B}$, and in particular, $b$ is an element of $A$.

Since $A$ was arbitrary element of $\mathscr A$, $b$ is in every element of $\mathscr A$ and therefore in $\bigcap\mathscr A$.

Comment: This was very readable! Good explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One should think of the sets participating in an intersection as "adding more and more restrictions" to the resulting intersection.

The **more** restrictions you have, the **smaller** is the set you get in the end.